# installing a program on guest account on windows 7

Tags: windows-7

I am required to use a pc I don't own and need to install programs (such as dreamweaver, etc.), but as the owner is on his holiday and I can't ask for his admin password.  Is there a way around this to install a program via GUEST account(it prompts for a password when installation commences)?

Comment: Try leaving the password blank.

Comment: You could using portable replacements for programs (try http://portableapps.com/). These run directly from a folder or USB drive without installation. You won't be able to use Dreamweaver though (could try something like KompoZer http://www.kompozer.net/ instead).

Answer (score 2):

There's no way (unless you hack the system somehow). This is one of the reasons the Guest account exists - to prevent Guests to do anything with your computer.

To be a bit constructive: back in XP days there was a default Administrator account which by default had no password. It was visible in recovery mode and if you changed the login screen so that you could enter user name, it worked in normal mode as well. I don't know if this is still the case for Win 7.

Comment: The local administrator is disabled by default in Windows Vista and 7.